# How to get Yii2 formatted error message in production systems?

Tags: error-handling, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

When Yii2 is used in debug mode and an error occurs, it shows a error message along with call trace, session, cookie and server info.

Sample image shown below.

[image]

In production ready systems, this will not be shown. However, Is there a way to pull this formatted html into a variable in production systems, so that it can be emailed to the developer to ease in debugging errors. If any one has any idea, please let me know.

I tried using `\Yii::$app->mailer->render()` passing `@vendor/yiisoft/yii2/views/errorHandler/exception.php` as view, `['exception => $ex]` as data, layout file as parameters. I'm getting undefined variable `handler` error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Config `Log Targets` for your purpose: 
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-logging.html